# Remove pre-installed apps (Candy Crush, Bubble Witch Saga, March of Empires) from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bloatware

I've been trying to remove Windows 10 Bloatware including Candy Crush Saga, Bubble Witch Saga, and Minecraft.

First, I tried simply uninstalling them, but the folders for these apps are not being removed and remain in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps.

The most common solution I've seen researching this issue is to remove the app package through Powershell, but doing this still does not remove the folders.

Is it safe to simply delete the folders corresponding to each app?

**Edit**

Don't mess with the permissions in the WindowsApps folder...can not launch Windows Store even after two resets (one keeping files and one removing them).

**Edit 2**

Ended up reinstalling a windows from a fresh iso. Only solution I have found.

Comment: Even with the folders still there, the app is removed by right-click > Uninstall. Is there a reason you wish to remove the folders?

Comment: "Is it safe to simply delete the folders corresponding to each app?" Yes.

Comment: The thing is that the folders still contain all of the app files, so they are taking up a good amount of space.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Windows from a fresh image. @Biswapriyo

Comment: If you run `icacls "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" /reset /t /c /q` after you finish your cleanup then "messing with permissions" will be reverted and Store starts working again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bulk Crap Uninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/) for uninstalling bloatware and it will also remove residual files.

Steps:

1. Download the program
2. Run the installer and open the program
3. Find the programs that you want to remove and check them
4. Click the uninstall button [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89jMo.png)
5. Confirm the apps you want to uninstall and click 'Continue'
6. Look through the settings and click 'Continue'
7. Click 'Begin Uninstallation'
8. Confirm the files and click delete
9. Wait until the uninstaller finishes
10. Click 'Search For Leftovers' to remove residual files

Comment: I cannot see candy crush listed in BCU

Comment: And I cannot see Bubble witch saga in BCU though it seems to be on my PC according to its thick folder

Answer (score 0):

You can try Windows' own CLI tool called [Winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) from the regular command shell.

List the installed programs:

```
winget list
```

The output will look like this:

```
Name                             Id                                     Version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
March of Empires: War of Lords   A278AB0D.MarchofEmpires_h6adky7gbf63m  8.0.0.0
....
```

Use the Id to uninstall the app:

```
winget uninstall A278AB0D.MarchofEmpires_h6adky7gbf63m
```